# Query result cached for minutes (?)

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm experiencing a very strange issue. I've a method that checks if an entity of a certain kind has a property set with a given value.
The method works, but sometimes the result seems to be cached for minutes or even hours.
When running the same query from the admin console I get the correct result.
My method is very simple, calling it with limit=1

```
public int countAccountByState(String state, int limit) throws ServletException {
    Query query = new Query(SharedGroupsAccount.KIND);
    query.setFilter(FilterOperator.EQUAL.of(SharedGroupsAccount.STATE, state));
    query.setKeysOnly();
    return datastore.prepare(query).countEntities(FetchOptions.Builder.withLimit(limit));
}
```

My app is getting result=1 even if no entity is matching the query when running from the admin console.

Comment: This is normal eventual consistency behavior.

Comment: I know that it may take a while until writes are visible in a query, but it is quite strange to get the stale result for ~30 minutes or so.